# Adding dimming view when tableView cell passes from the middle of scrollView

Tags: swift, view, scrollview, rect

I have scrollView. In this scrollView I have another view. In this view I have tableView.

ScrollView>View>TableView

The cells of the tableView are custom and have labels in it.

I need when the label passes thru the center of the scrollView to appear a dimmingView and only the label to be visible.

So I have to use scrollViewDidScroll and inside to add:

```
let rectOfCell = theTableView!.rectForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
let rectOfCellInSuperview = theTableView!.convert(rectOfCell, to: scrollView)
```

I don't know if this code is going to work, because I don't know how to put the dimming view with only label visible.

After the rect of the label passes thru the middle of the scrollView I need dimming view to appear. How to do that ?

Comment: you are trying something like picker right , just instead only the middle cell will be dimmed ?

Comment: no, everything will be dimmed only the cell will be visible, like example of @Vicaren , but showing the dimming view only when the cell at IndexPath(row:0,section:0) pass the middle of the scrollView. The scrollView is not the scrollView of the tableView. The scrollView is another var